# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'?

Tags: python

I dont understand why i am getting the error of `">="` I thought i might have called something wrong.

> ```
> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'?
> ```

```
def determineLetterGrade(letterGd, testAverage):

    if (testAverage >= 90) and (testAverage <= 100):
        letterGd = "A.";
    else:
        if (testAverage >= 87) and (testAverage <= 89.99):
            letterGd = "B+.";
        else:
            if  (testAverage >= 80 and (testAverage <= 86.99)):
                letterGd = "B."
            else:
                if  (testAverage >= 77) and (testAverage <= 79.99):
                    letterGd = "C+. ";
                else:
                    if  (testAverage >= 70) and (testAverage <= 76.99):
                        letterGd = "C.";
                    else:
                        if  (testAverage >= 67) and (testAverage <= 69.99):
                            letterGd = "D+.";
                        else:      
                            if (testAverage >= 60) and (testAverage <= 66.99) :                  
                                letterGd = "D. ";
                            else:                       
                                letterGd = "F.";  
    return letterGd; 

def writeSortedList(count, finalCount, name, testAverage, outFile):
    count = 0;
    outFile.write("SORTED TEST AVERAGE LIST (LOWEST TO HIGHEST)" + "\n"); #writes the Label/title
    outFile.write("=" * 110 + "\n");
    while (count < finalCount):
        outFile.write(format(format(name[count], "30s") + format(" : ", "^5s") + format(testAverage[count], "6.2f") +  format(" -> ", "^5s") +  + "\n"));
        count = count + 1;
        #end while loop
    outFile.write("=" * 110 + "\n");
    outFile.write("\n");
    # End writeSortedList function
```

Comment: How do you call `determineLetterGrade`?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Please include **all** relevant code and data. See: [mcve].

Comment: Please always include the complete error traceback in your question - it's essential in order to know where the error happened and what lead to it.

Comment: We need to know what arguments you are using to call `determineLetterGrade`. It seems you may be passing in a list to `testAverage`.  You'll also want to look into using `elif`s to clean up your if statements

Comment: Also, why are you using semicolons? Why are you using the `letterGd` parameter in that way? Why are you writing `else if` instead of `elif`? Why are you seemingly passing a file object to `writeSortedList()` instead of a file name, or just having it operate on strings? I’m guessing you’re not using a context manager for that file, either? Why the while loop with a counter in place of a for loop? Why are you calling the `format()` function like that, or even at all? Is this actually Python, are you trolling?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile : This looks like bad Java code written in Python.

Comment: `format(testAverage[count]` - this implies that testAverage is some kind of container/sequence - and the error message confirms it - you need to figure out what it is and figure out why you have chosen to make comparisons with it and an `int`.

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your determineLetterGrade() function in a Python readable format:

```
def determine_letter_grade(test_average):
    if 90 <= test_average <= 100:
        letter_gd = "A."
    elif 87 <= test_average <= 89.99:
        letter_gd = "B+."
    elif 80 <= test_average <= 86.99:
        letter_gd = "B."
    elif 77 <= test_average <= 79.99:
        letter_gd = "C+. "
    elif 70 <= test_average <= 76.99:
        letter_gd = "C."
    elif 76 <= test_average <= 69.99:
        letter_gd = "D+."
    elif 60 <= test_average <= 66.99:
        letter_gd = "D. "
    else:
        letter_gd = "F."
    print(letter_gd)
```

Also I recommend you using meaningful name for functions/classes/variables. Instead of `letter_gd`, it's recommended to use `letter_grade`.

So, when you call this function with a parameter, you get the result.
`determine_letter_grade(90)` gets you the result `A+.`

Comment: Shouldn’t the function return the value, instead of printing it? It’s probably bad design.

Comment: I have used print function for getting the result only. You can use return statement if you want to store and use it later.

Comment: It’s better design to have it return a value, is what I’m saying.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: I dont understand why i am getting the error of `">="`

You are trying to compare a value of type `list` with a value of type `int`.

> E.g.: `testAverage` is of type `list` and `90` is of type `int`
>
> ```
> testAverage >= 90
> ```

Consider the following:

```
def get_grade(average):
    if not isinstance(average, float):
        raise ValueError("Argument 'average' have to be of type 'float', got {}"
                  .format(type(average)))

    for r0, r1, g in ((90.0, 100.0, "A."), (87.0, 89.99, "B+."), 
                      (80.0, 86.99, "B."), (77.0, 79.99, "C+."), 
                      (70.0, 76.99, "C."), (67.0, 69.99, "D+."), 
                      (60.0, 66.99, "D.")):
        if average >= r0 and average <= r1:
            return g
    else:                       
        return "F."

print(get_grade([67.0]))
```

> **This will throw:**
>   `ValueError: Argument 'average' have to be of type 'float', got <class 'list'>`

**But doing:** `print(get_grade(67.0))` will output: `D+.`